# How to get Dynamic Imports working on Rollup.js

Tags: javascript, rollup, rollupjs

I am trying to `rollup` a icon library using `vue`

I have a folder full of `.svg`

I run a command to scan the folders with all the `.svgs` and convert them to

```
export default `svg`;
```

and change the file to `iconName.js`

In the `.vue` document i require the correct file using :

```
Promise.resolve(
        import(`./icons/${this.iconSet}/${this.icn}`)
          .then(v => {
            console.log('required', v)
            this.svg = v.default
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log('err', e)
            this.error = true
          })
      )
```

In development, the `.vue` icon component works.
In production as an npm package i get:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received 'B:\\icons\\node_modules\\\u0000commonjs-dynamic-register:\\icons\\brands\\500px.js\\package.json'
```

-> `500px.js` is the first file in the icon pack and not the one being required by the `vue` component.
-> No clue why package.json is being appended (the files are contained within the `dist` folder - hoping relative paths would work but no luck

The above statement seems to be rendered from `rollup` via:

```
require("\u0000commonjs-dynamic-register:B:/icons/dist/icons/brands/500px.js")
```

B:/icons/dist -> the computer's path to the repo -> i believe i have to shorten it to:

```
require("\u0000commonjs-dynamic-register:/icons/brands/500px.js")
```

Which gives me the same error

I'm lost and have spent days looking into this
thanks

https://github.com/mjmnagy/rollup-error-Sept-01-2020

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue:

```
  **import(`./icons/${this.iconSet}/${this.icn}`)**
```

Rollup doesnt handle "dynamic"/lazy loading like this as it doesnt know what or what not to include(no tree-shaking)

If you change the import to include the relevant documents ie:

```
import * as icons from  './icons'
```

There isnt an issue with `rollup` However there is now an issue that you have included every `.svg` which is a lot to load.

if you refer to `font-awesome` their package actually forces u to specifically name icon packages or specific icons.

My solution as i want them all to be available on demand, was to kill this and move into `.svg sprites`

HTH